# Crash on sizeWithAttributes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

An argument of my dictionary looks to be nil but i have no idea why... I've browsed SOF and all propositions are like this.

```
CGSize size;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] 
                compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // here it works
    size = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" 
                                                size:15.0f]];
} else {
    // here it crashes
    size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" 
                                     size:15.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
}
```

// console output

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Comment: See also [What happened to “HelveticaNeue-Italic” on iOS 7.0.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527962/what-happened-to-helveticaneue-italic-on-ios-7-0-3)

Comment: @MartinR than you for your comment. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Or the question may be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Err, no.  Duplicate questions don't require an accepted answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe That's why i wrote 'or' ;) Anyway, voted to close my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:15.0f]
```

returns `nil` (no longer available) hence you are essentially doing

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:nil forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
```

which raises an exception.

Comment: Why not simply vote for the dupe indicated my @MartinR?

Comment: I have, just adding the reason for the exception when creating the dictionary, which may not be obvious to the OP given how he phrased the question...

Comment: After reading the attached link i saw what happened and didn't need more explanation. Your comment is rather harsh given that i simply asked a question and got the response. The answer from @MartinR is enough for everyone.

Comment: I really meant no offence.