# How to set font name of UILabel as HelveticaNeue Thin in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uifont

I am creating UILabel, for the label i can set the font name as HelveticaNeue Regular, Light, UltraLight etc, But i unable to set the font name as HelveticaNeue Thin, it is not working as expected. I did like,

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:16];
```

Also i have searched on Google didnt got any solution. How to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the font to your project if you are using a custom Font

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Helvetica Neue Thin is already bundled in iOS (7, at least).

Comment: please check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527962/what-happened-to-helveticaneue-italic-on-ios-7-0-3

Comment: May be you can find your answer here here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697354/1790571

Comment: same link that i have past @HimanshuJoshi :)

Comment: @NitinGohel i have given internal link to answer :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This font is bundled with iOS 7, so if you're targeting iOS 7 and above your

`label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:16.0f];`

will work.

However if you are targeting iOS 6.1 and below you'll need to [embed the font](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: It crashes the application

Answer (score 19):

Updated answer to support swift

```
    let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16.0)!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UIFontDescriptor *helveticaNeueFamily =
    [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:
        @{ UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: @"Helvetica Neue" }];
NSArray *matches =
    [helveticaNeueFamily matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys: nil];
```

The matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys: method as shown returns an array of font descriptors for all the Helvetica Neue fonts on the system, such as HelveticaNeue, HelveticaNeue-Medium, HelveticaNeue-Light, **HelveticaNeue-Thin**, and so on.

You can modify the fonts returned by preferredFontForTextStyle: by applying symbolic traits, such as bold, italic, expanded, and condensed. You can use font descriptors to modify particular traits, as shown in Listing 9-2.

referenced by [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html)

or

this font you can't apply directly.

so you can customize your font

[How to use custom fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me. Write this code below your label declarations.

It sets **all the UILabel** under a function with same font.

```
[[UILabel appearance]setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:32.0f]];
```

To set font to **particular UILabel** use this code :

```
[labelName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15.0f]];
```

Comment: This does seem to work for me too, however googling suggests that it shouldn't work, confused.