# How to set text font as System Thin in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, programmatically-created

I want to set label text as System Thin. Read in StackOverflow and found an answer like this:

```
labelDescriptionView.font = UIFont(name: "System-Thin", size: 15.0)
```

but it did not work. How can I improve my code and make Thin font style programmatically?

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: @MartinR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091367/how-to-set-font-name-of-uilabel-as-helveticaneue-thin-in-ios here

Comment: @MartinR oh, I misunderstood the answer =/

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade its already given, set font name "HelveticaNeue-Thin" as iOS uses "HelveticaNeue" as default font. There is no font specified "System-Thin" in iOS only Bold, Italic & Regular are there for System font.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara but I can set it to Thin from the File Inspecter

Comment: @DipenPanchasara as of iOS 9 `HelveticaNeue` is no longer the default font!

Comment: @rckoenes i know its removed in iOS 9 but prior to that its available. Though you can check font availability by iOS version [here](http://iosfonts.com/) @OrkhanAlizade to set thin font there is no specific method like `boldSystemFontOfSize` in iOS, though you can set it explicitly using [UIFont fontWithName:@""] method.

Comment: I want Thin font, guys =/

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade set it programatically.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara my question sounds exactly so. How to set it programmatically?

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade: Did you even try a Google search for "ios system thin font"? It took me less than one minute to find the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `system` font in the Interface Builder is the OS default font, it is not a font you can get by it's name. For the system font Apple provides the following methods:

```
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
+ (UIFont *)italicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize;
```

These do not include any thin version but iOS 8.2 onwards you can use:

```
+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize weight:(CGFloat)weight;
```

Where you can pass: as weights:

```
UIFontWeightUltraLight
UIFontWeightThin
UIFontWeightLight
UIFontWeightRegular
UIFontWeightMedium
UIFontWeightSemibold
UIFontWeightBold
UIFontWeightHeavy
```

So a thin system font would be:

```
UIFont *thinFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15 weight:UIFontWeightThin];
```

Answer (score 16):

If you're using iOS 8.2 or higher you can use this;

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15, weight: UIFontWeightThin)
```

For previous versions just use `HelveticaNeue-Thin` as your font.

Edit: for iOS 14 it is:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)
```